# How does Kitty Pryde know/learn to control her time travel power

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

In the film *Days of Future Past* it is explained that only the person that is sent back remembers the other timeline, and Kitty Pryde herself does not remember the other timeline. Given this, everytime Kitty were to use her powers, it would be the first time in her timeline.

Therefore how could she possibly

- Know anything about her abilities
- Learn to control her ability
- Learn the limitations of her ability

Comment: I don't recall it ever being stated that it was kitty's first time using her powers.

Comment: @ChristopherLee "only the person that is sent back remembers the other timeline" so in the new timeline, Kitty hasn't used her powers yet.

Comment: That still does not mean she has not used her powers before this.

Comment: @ChristopherLee Yes it does. If there was a reason to use her power, then they wouldn't be in that timeline. Kitty would have used her powers and they would be in another timeline. Please, think 4 dimensionally for a second will you...

Comment: So lets say she learns she can do this 5 years prior to the film. So she casually trains this skill set. Perhaps Prof. X helps her prioritize her skills in her new power. Now when the film happens it is not her first time using her powers. Like I said, "I do not recall it ever being stated that when we see here in the film, it is the first time using her powers.".

Comment: @ChristopherLee It is clear you don't understand causality. Please stop replying. The by product of each usage of her powers is to make it such that she never used her powers. Can you understand how that works? HOW do you train a power which you can't remember using?

Comment: Why can't she remember using her powers in the years up to the event?

Comment: Where is it stated that the events of the film is the fist time she uses her powers?

Comment: Also, Kitty sends her own mind into the past, so she remembers it all.

Comment: @ChristopherLee FFS. My statement comes from the logical framework and rules that were stated for her powers. "only the person that is sent back remembers the other timeline". Thus when the timeline changes, Kitty DOES NOT REMEMBER THE TIMELINE WHERE SHE USED HER POWER. PLEASE STOP REPLYING. You obviously do NOT understand time travel. It is clear that the writers choose one of the forms of Erased Timeline solution of time travel paradox. If it were "Novikov self-consistency principle" then yeah, she could remember using her powers. But then there would be no movie.

Comment: You tagged this as the comic not the film. You are talking about Kitty Pride of the comic and not of the film correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17353/discussion-between-aron-and-christopher-lee).

Comment: The rules you state do not cause a paradox. You can see this by answering the following question: When does Kitty first learn about her time travel powers?

Comment: I'd like to point out that, in reality, none of us understand time travel. Even our best scientists are just making it up as they go, based on educational guesses. What we see in movies or read in books is just someone's guess as to how it would work. Therefore, getting upset with someone because they "do NOT understand time travel" is somewhat silly.

Comment: I think the key point is that just because she sends someone back, it doesn't mean the timeline is altered so that she doesn't send them back.  Maybe they just change what shirt they put on that day.

Comment: @Omegacron: _Even our best scientists are just making it up as they go, based on educational guesses_ Sorry, but no, **there is an abundance of hard science that points to timetravel being utterly impossible**, there are some theoritically models (_with lots of if's and but's_) and those are **all** limited in that [there is no way a traveler can go back in time to before the time machine was built](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/review/dr-marc-space/time-travel.html)

Answer (score 9):

If Kitty discovered this ability in a non-life-threatening occasion, then she could conceivably remember things.  If she learns to send someone back in time, and tests it when there's no need to radically change the timeline, then after the time traveling is complete, she'd still be in a timeline where she used her power.

Then just extrapolate that out to her practicing and learning (via talking to the time traveler about how practice went), and she's able to accumulate experience and knowledge of the time travel ability.

This isn't outlined in the film, but it's my educated guess on how it could be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

1. Send someone back.
2. That person makes no changes.
3. That person comes back and she will still remember the single time line.

In general, so long as changes don't change the fact that she is using time travel, then she 'll remember that time travel was used.

So how does she know what happens when changes are made?  The person who remembers tells her afterward.  And she has to tell that person what happened in the new timeline.  For example, at the end of **X-Men:  Days of Future Past**

> Logan was surprised to find out that Jean Grey was alive in that new timeline.

She may not remember using her powers that time in the new timeline, but she can still learn about it from the person who does remember.

Not every change is as significant as the change from **Days of Future Past**.  Part of the issue here is the paradox problem.  If she uses her powers to make a change, then the change will obviate the need to use her powers.  But if she is using her powers as a test, then she'll still want to do the test in both timelines.

Tests can also be insignificant.  Send someone to perform some task, e.g. set a die to have the six on top.  Send someone back in time to change the six to a one right after the change.  Then go check it after they get back.  That wouldn't prevent her from remembering using her powers, because the visible change occurs after the use of powers has stopped.

Even if there is a change, it doesn't matter if the change doesn't change the use of time travel.  Make the decision to use time travel before the changed time and stick to it after the change is made.  Then Kitty will remember using time travel in both timelines.

Most of this is speculative.  We don't see her testing her powers in the movie.  But the question was

> Therefore how could she possibly

This is how it is possible.  Since she does know things about how her powers work in the movie, we can assume that she did something like this.  But we don't know how thorough she was or her exact process.